# Script to qsub some .sh executables

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cygwin, qsub

In shell cygwin (ubuntu) is it possible to make an script that calls inside to qsub serial?

(Sorry if it's a duplicate..., i have no idea of how to ask it)

Comment: can you call this qsub from command line ?

Comment: Yes you can, it's for submitting works for a cluster made in Rocks. Also it's possible to make aliases for .bashrc with qsub and its options.